# Initialisation statement in for loop

Tags: javascript

i want to know what happens when we don't use it
eg

```
    for(;i<=10;i++)
    {    
}
```

I searched some sites but i am very confused.
Thanks.

Comment: @charlietfl I mean to say how will it evaluate?

Comment: It gives an error, `i` wouldn't be defined, in this case(that is after correcting the syntax)

Comment: if there's no initialisation statement, there's nothing to evaluate, so, it's all good ... not sure why you wouldn't try it first to see what happens

Comment: @dvenkatsagar - you're correct, as long as `i` isn't declared outside of this snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first off, it will give an error saying that `i` is not defined. But if you declare it ahead of the loop, it works fine:

```
var i = 0;    
for(;i<=10;i++){
  console.log(i);
}
```

You can also remove the termination statement as well, and keep it in the loop like this :

```
var i = 0;    
for(;i<=10;){
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

It'll work, I hope that answers your question...

Its similar to a `while` loop where you initialize a variable first and then keep the loop with the comparison and the terminate it with a termination statement. So according to the code in your question, what you are basically do is something like this:

```
while(i <= 10){
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

Which will give an error.